# Kontsevich's lecture at Rutgers (1996)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, reference-request

Reading some papers about (homological) mirror symmetry I have found the reference to the unpublished Kontsevich's lecture at Rutgers University (Nov 11, 1996). I would like to know if someone has some notes of this lecture. I really want to know in some detail (as far as possible) what Kontsevich said in that talk. I think it is not easy to find notes of the talk (15 years after!) but I would also appreciate comments about it (for example, the main ideas presented, etc)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could always email him :)

Comment: Have you looked there?: http://193.51.104.7/~maxim/TEXTS/